# saving custom post type data to different table in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

As the title says, is there any option to save the data in different table in wordpress.

I have around 10000+ data in my site in a different table. I have moved this table inside wordpress database and i have created custom post and now I want to show the data from my own table not from wp_posts.

Any ideas, suggestion or example.

Comment: This had pretty big edit by anonymous user, which I rejected because it moved question away from original and answers. Please ask such as new question.

Comment: you could use PODs plugin to store data in custom table https://pods.io/tutorials/how-tos-sceencasts-series/using-pods-pages-with-advanced-content-types/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: move the data from the custom table into the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables, as a custom post type.

It will save you a lot of effort, in the long run.